# how to model ADN & ARN in haskell?

Tags: design, haskell

I would like to modelize some nucleotid chains : ADN & ARN.
ADN is a list of nucleotids : A,T,G,C.
ARN is a list of nucleotids : A,U,G,C.

ideally, I would like to define e.g. ADN as a list of data types A,T,G,C.
I have this code, which works but doesn't suffice:

```
data NtADN = Td | Ad | Cd | Gd deriving (Eq)
    data NtARN = Ur | Ar | Cr | Gr deriving (Eq)
    data ADN = ADN [NtADN] deriving (Eq)
    data ARN = ARN [NtARN] deriving (Eq)


    class NucleotidChain a where
        valid :: a -> Bool
        countACGX :: a -> (Int,Int,Int,Int)
```

but I'm not satisfied with it : the nucleotids are declared 2 times with arbitrary suffixes (Ad,Ar...)

moreover, countACGX, which counts the number of each nucleotid in ADNs & ARNs, must be declared 2 times, one for ADN and one for ARN:

```
instance NucleotidChain ADN where
        valid (ADN s) = all (\t->(t==Ad)|| (t==Td)||(t==Cd)||(t==Gd)) s 
        countACGX (ADN s) = 
            let     a= length $ elemIndices Ad s 
                    c= length $ elemIndices Cd s 
                    g= length $ elemIndices Gd s 
                    t= length $ elemIndices Td s 
            in (a,c,g,t) 

    instance NucleotidChain ARN where
        valid (ARN s) = all (\t-> (t==Ur) || (t==Ar) || (t==Cr) || (t==Gr)) s
        countACGX (ARN s) = 
            let     a= length $ elemIndices Ar s 
                    c= length $ elemIndices Cr s 
                    g= length $ elemIndices Gr s 
                    u= length $ elemIndices Ur s 
            in (a,c,g,u)
```

is there a way to get rid of this duplication?to declare only 5 nucleotids (A,T,G,C,U) and especially why not to success in declaring a data ADN (and ARN) as an array of elements taken in the result of a function which is different for ADN (& ARN)?
such as it:

```
data Nt = A | T | G | C | U
data ADN = ADN [nts]
data ARN = ARN [nts]

class NtChain a where
  nts :: [Nt]
```

Comment: If this is a design question (“how can I model ADN & ARN?”) you need to provide more details: Why is your current model is insufficient? What you are trying to represent? I remember my biology lessons back in school only vaguely. If this is a coding question (“Is there a way to get rid of this duplication?”), maybe the question should be moved to Stack Overflow?

Comment: well, I think it's a question between coding and modeling, typically an haskell question. for the modeling part, ADN is as a sequence of 4 'letters' (nucleotids) : A,T,C,G; whereas ARN is a sequence of A,U,G,C. nothing more is needed in order to model these 2 things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current model is good because it keeps the symbols in ADN & ARN strings completely separate – you can't accidentally put a `U` into an ADN string because it's part of a different type. Let's keep that.

From that it follows that your `valid` function is superfluous because it is guaranteed to always return true – the type system won't allow a malformed string.

If you want to write an ADN string as `[t,a,g,c]` instead of `[Td,Ad,Cd,Gd]`, we can use a type class to define a polymorphic nullary function:

```
class ProvidesT a where t :: a
class ProvidesA a where a :: a
class ProvidesG a where g :: a
class ProvidesC a where c :: a
class ProvidesU a where u :: a
```

Then we can provide instances for `NtADN`:

```
instance ProvidesT NtADN where t = Td
```

and so on for all cases. Doing this for such short method names is not a good idea though because they might be accidentally shadowed by local variables. (It might be possible to declare a type constructor within the class with the “type families” extension, but I have no experience with that).

Is this tedious? Yes, but that's Haskell. You could consider using template Haskell to automate the instance definitions, but that might be more work than just spelling out everything.

Your `countACGX` method is not a design flaw, though the implementation could be refined substantially. Just define `count symbol = length $ elemIndices symbol s` as a helper, then the function simplifies to `(count Ad, count Cd, ...)`.

Comment: ok, but just one more question : is there a way to get rid of the countACGX duplication? for other methods like countACGX there could be the same problem... resulting in a very long program

Comment: @lolveley I don't think you can get rid of the duplication entirely, but you can factor out the common part – which is counting a tuple of items and returning the count. Once you extract a generic `count`, each `countACGX` is only a single line. Having to type that out for each set of nucleids etc. is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of defining a flat list

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
module Lib
    ( Nucleotide
    , DNA
    , RNA
    , NucleotideType
    , a, t, g, c, u
    ) where

data Nucleotide a = T | A | G | C | U deriving Eq

data DNA
data RNA

class NucleotideType a where
  switch :: f DNA -> f RNA -> f a

instance NucleotideType DNA where
  switch = \ dna _ -> dna

instance NucleotideType RNA where
  switch = \ _ rna -> rna

a :: (NucleotideType t) => Nucleotide t
a = A

t :: Nucleotide DNA
t = T

u :: Nucleotide RNA
u = U

g :: (NucleotideType t) => Nucleotide t
g = G

c :: (NucleotideType t) => Nucleotide t
c = C
```

The idea is that we use phantom types to mark each nucleotide as either DNA or RNA (declaring a "closed" type family to encompass them) and use smart constructors to make sure consumers of our module can only make `t` as DNA and `u` as RNA. (Note that we must not export the normal constructors.)

We can then deduplicate the `count` function as

```
countNucleotideBase :: [Nucleotide t] -> (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
countNucleotideBase xs =
  let [a, t, c, g, u] = map (\n -> length . elemIndices n $ xs) [A, T, C, G, U]
  in (a, t, c, g, u)

countNucleotideDNA :: [Nucleotide DNA] -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
countNucleotideDNA xs = 
  let (a, t, c, g, u) = countNucleotideBase xs
  in (a, t, c, g)
```

---

As a different answer that relies on true type safety rather than encapsulation, we can use GADTs to truly encode that `T` is only `DNA` while `G` is either `DNA` or `RNA`, say, we can say

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module Lib
    ( NT(..)
    , N(..)
    , countDNA
    ) where

import Data.Kind(Type)

data NT = DNA | RNA

data N :: NT -> Type where
  T :: N 'DNA
  U :: N 'RNA
  C :: N  t
  G :: N  t
  A :: N  t
```

The nice thing about this is we can expose the data constructors directly and still get full type safety (e.g. the expression `[T, C, U]` is ill-typed). The problem here is that like your first solution we cannot generalize over `N 'DNA` and `N 'RNA`. To do so, we can use Existential Types to get hide that pesky variable.

```
data W = forall t. W (N t)

countBase :: [W] -> (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) 
countBase ws =
  let [t, u, c, g, a] = map (\ w -> length . filter (== w) $ ws) [W T, W U, W C, W G, W A]
  in (t, u, c, g, a)

instance Eq W where
  (W T) == (W T) = True
  (W U) == (W U) = True
  (W C) == (W C) = True
  (W G) == (W G) = True
  (W A) == (W A) = True
  _     == _     = False
```

This comes with some hassle and some performance harms in use as to use these general functions we have to wrap and potentially unwrap our arguments in `W`. e.g.

```
countDNA :: [N 'DNA] -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
countDNA xs =
  let (t, _, c, g, a) = countBase (map W xs)
  in (t, c, g, a)
```

---

Although the latter of these is probably a bit closer to how a Haskell guru (which I certainly am not) might solve this problem, it has serious downsides: while solutions can achieve typesafety while being relatively concise, they buy this at a lot of complexity. If everyone working on your codebase is comfortable with all the latest GHC Extensions and the quasi-dependent programming they enable, then go for it. This describes a small percentage even of people who know some Haskell and could ultimately harm your project (again, depending on who your collaborators or/will be); in those cases I would look for mechanisms like smart constructors and type classes that provide at least runtime safety for much lower barrier to entry.